# Nodejs cipher.setAAD(buffer) vs Java chiper.updateAAD(byte[]), will i get the same authTag?

Tags: java, node.js, encryption

I am working on a project in Nodejs which suppose to encrypt plaintext and send the encrypted text to the Java program, and java side is able to decrypt it. Before decrypting it, java side needs to verify the authTag first.

I am using the build-in Nodejs crypto, the [cipher.setAAD](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_setaad_buffer) function only takes a buffer as a parameter, which actually is **unsigned** 8-bit Array (Uint8Array). However, Java [cipher.updateAAD](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#updateAAD(byte[])) uses byteArray which is **signed** byte array.

Both AAD are generated from the same hex string.

So am I able to get the same authTag?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java `byte` is signed but the bytes in the arrays used in Java crypto -- not just AAD but also plaintext, ciphertext, hashes/MACs/signatures, keys, certificates, etc, etc, and also OS-level I/O like `File{Input,Output}Stream` -- are taken modulo 256, effectively making them unsigned -- and the values you put in them should be in the range 0..255 *converted to* `byte`.

Note the Java decrypt operation for an AEAD cipher doesn't give you the authtag; instead you give it the ciphertext PLUS authtag and IT does the comparison, throwing an exception if there is a mismatch.

Also note the only AEAD mode supported by 'normal' Java (with the Sun-now-Oracle and OpenJDK providers) is GCM (with AES). BouncyCastle also supports CCM, and I don't know about IBM or others like Android. Your nodejs-crypto link says it supports only GCM, which surprises me since it uses OpenSSL underneath and that supports both GCM and CCM since OpenSSL 1.0.1.

Assuming you use a mode supported on both sides, these modes are standardized and deterministic, so if you use the same key, nonce, plaintext or ciphertext as applicable, and AAD **yes they will produce/expect the same tag** and interoperate.